# Array of pointers to struct

Tags: c

I have a struct like so

```
typedef struct person {
 int id;
 char name[20];
} Person;
```

Then, outside of the function, I have a pointer array of pointers to these structs, like so

```
Person **people;
```

Then in the function I am adding people to the array like so (in a loop)

```
Person person;

for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
  person.id = i;
  person.name = nameArray[i];
  people[i] = &person;
}
```

`person` is being added to the `people` array but when (in VS2010) I go to the Watch screen and type `people, 50`
I just see the same `person` in every slot as if when adding the next person, it changes all previous as well. What am I doing wrong here?

Also, to retrieve a certain person's name, is this the right syntax?

`people[0] -> name;`  Or is it  `people[0][0].name`?

Thanks!

Comment: Sidenote about a deleted question: I was just writing an answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485491/read-string-from-stdin-maintain-string-length when you deleted it.

Comment: Sorry about that. Felt it may not have been a very productive questions for the site.

Comment: Nevermind. The idea was: Set the whole `char[20]` to all `'\0'` before calling `fscanf`. After `fscanf` returns, do `for(int i=19;i>=0; i--) {if(s[i]=='\0') s[i]=' '; else break;}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What do you expect? You are making all the pointers point to the same `Person`. And when `person` goes out of scope, all the pointers in your array (which are all the same) will be invalid and point to a deallocated block of memory. You have to use `malloc` in each iteration of the loop to allocate dynamic storage and create a `Person` that won't go away till you `free` it:

```
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
  Person *person = malloc(sizeof(Person));
  person->id = i;
  person->name = nameArray[i];
  people[i] = person;

  /* or:
  people[i] = malloc(sizeof(Person));
  people[i]->id = i;
  people[i]->name = nameArray[i];

  it does the same thing without the extra temporary variable
  */
}

// then when you are done using all the Person's you created...
for (i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    free(people[i]);
```

Alternatively, you could have an array of `Person`s instead of `Person*`s and what you are doing would work:

```
Person people[50];

Person person;

for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
  person.id = i;
  person.name = nameArray[i];
  people[i] = person; // make a copy
}
```

And with that way you don't have to `free` anything.

Answer (score 2):

> I just see the same 'person' in every slot...

Right, because you use the same `Person` each time.  You are *reassigning* its members, so the last assignment sticks and your pointers all point to the same chunk of memory.

Also realize that you're storing the address of a variable with automatic storage duration (i.e., stack allocated).  That memory will (probably) be cleaned up when the function exits and dereferencing any of those pointers at a later time will result in undefined behavior.

You should be using dynamic allocation if you need to initialize the array in the function and keep it valid when the function exits.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate memory for each person:

```
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
  people[i] = (person*)malloc(sizeof(person)); // dynamic memory allocation
  people[i]->id = i;
  people[i]->name = nameArray[i];
}
```

The address `&person` of `person` does not change in your original version, so you have a bunch of pointers pointing on the same data, which will change on every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way you have written this, you have initialized each pointer to the same instance of Person, examine:

```
Person person; // this allocates a single person

for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
  person.id = i;
  person.name = nameArray[i];
  people[i] = &person;
}
```

What you need to do is allocate dynamically each person, as so:

```
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
  Person* person = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
  person->id = i;
  person->name = nameArray[i];
  people[i] = person;
}
```

Don't forget to free all the memory after you're done, so at the end of your code:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<50; i++)
  free(people[i]);
free(people);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to allocate space for each `person`. Your code as it is right now only has one `person` struct that you are reusing, and all of those pointers are pointing to the same address.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are all correct.  The only thing I can add is, besides not creating a new `Person`, you are also allocating it on the stack when you should be using the heap.  Make sure you understand why the following "quick change" to your existing code is bad:

```
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
  Person person;   /* <--- BAD. Make sure you understand why. */

  person.id = i;
  person.name = nameArray[i];
  people[i] = &person;
}
```

This makes a new `Person` each time, using your old way of creating person.  Again, please be sure you understand why this is wrong and the other answers (using `malloc`) are right.